# How do I post insecurely, using basic auth, to a RESTful server?

Tags: java, rest

How do I do the equivalent of this:

```
curl \
  --insecure \
  --request POST \
  --header "<header>" \
  --data "<Complex JSON Object>" \
  "https://<username>:<password>@<URL>?<params>"
```

in Java?

The authentication is weird and only works if I use the `--insecure` flag and the basic authentication.

I've tried all sorts of libraries, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: `-k` / `--insecure` is documented as "Allow connections to SSL sites without certs (H)"; but your site isn't an SSL site, so that flag shouldn't have any effect. Are you sure that your command means what you intend?

Comment: Yes. I know what it does. I forgot the "s" when I posted this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: OK. So, is your problem that you don't know how to achieve the equivalent of `--insecure`, or that you don't know how to achieve basic auth, or . . . ?

Comment: @ruakh I don't know how to achieve the equivalent of `--insecure`.

Comment: Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" curl -k -X POST --header \"Content-Type: application/json\"  -d '"+body+"' https://u.r.l. ");
 process.waitFor();
 process.destroy();

Answer (score -1):

There are a ton http client libraries. One of the most popular is Apache Commons HTTP Client. You can use it to post JSON like this:

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com");

String json = "{"id":1,"name":"John"}";
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
assertThat(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), equalTo(200));
client.close();
```

Comment: I need it to have the -k (--insecure) flag. 
It just returns:
`Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`